# Vacuum permittivity vs 1/(36π) nF/m

Tags: electromagnetism, history, physical-constants

[Vacuum permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity) is $ϵ_0\approx8.8541878128×10^{−12}\,\mathrm{F⋅m^{−1}}$. Therefore, within 0.14%, $ϵ_0\approx\displaystyle\frac 1 {36\,π}\,\mathrm{nF⋅m^{−1}}$, thus $\displaystyle4\,π\,ϵ_0\approx \frac 1 9 \mathrm{nF}⋅\mathrm m^{−1}$. That comes handy in electronics engineering (I've even [seen](https://www.emisoftware.com/calculator/wire-pair-capacitance/) equality stated).

Is that purely accidental, or is there some reason for it, like perhaps the historical definition of the Farad or Volt?

Comment: In cgs units, charge is measured in esu and potential in esu/cm. The unit of capacitance
is thus just the centimetre! 1 cm is equal 1.11 pF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old definition of the constant for the vacuum permeability is
$\mu_0 = 4\pi \cdot 10^{-7} H/m $ (since the redefiniton of SI units in 2019, the experimental value is still close). Then your observation follows from the speed of light in vacuum and solving for vacuum permittivity: $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{c^2\mu_0} $, when approximating $c \approx 3 
\cdot 10^8 m/s $.

Comment: Good answer.  To answer the OP's final question, it's "accidental" in the sense that the speed of light is pretty close to a round number in SI units.  But it does stem from historical definitions as well.